# javascript innerhtml won't set value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to generate the random color code and also I want to display that color code into SPAN. Tried this below code,

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        randomColor = "#" + ("000000" + randomColor).slice(-6);
        document.bgColor = randomColor;
        document.getElementById("hexRandomColor").innerHTML = randomColor;
  </script>

  <div class="container">
      <span id="hexRandomColor"></span>
  <div>
</body>
```

But, it (**document.getElementById("hexRandomColor").innerHTML = randomColor;**) didn't show the color code in span. It works, When I move the script code outside of body. But, I want to keep script code inside the body element. How do I display the color code?

Comment: The `<script>` should be at end tag `</body>`

Comment: You can simplify color calculation by using: `'#'+Math.random().toString(16).slice(-6).padEnd(6,'0')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is executing before DOM is fully loaded which causes the element unavailable when trying to set the style and throws error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

To solve the issue, you can either place the script at the bottom of the *body* or wrap your code with [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) which will ensure that the code inside will be executed only after the DOM is fully loaded.

```html
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
       var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
       randomColor = "#" + ("000000" + randomColor).slice(-6);
       document.bgColor = randomColor;
       document.getElementById("hexRandomColor").innerHTML = randomColor;
    });        
  </script>

  <div class="container">
      <span id="hexRandomColor"></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.onload`. Because when the script is executed the element doesnot exist

```html
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function(){
            var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
            randomColor = "#" + ("000000" + randomColor).slice(-6);
            document.bgColor = randomColor;
            document.getElementById("hexRandomColor").innerHTML = randomColor;
        }
  </script>

  <div class="container">
      <span id="hexRandomColor"></span>
  <div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `script` near the closing tag of body(`</body>`). The script is running before `span` is rendered in the `DOM`.`Span` is not in the `DOM` yet Hence you are getting `cannot set innerHTML of null error`.

```html
<body>

 <div class="container">
      <span id="hexRandomColor"></span>
  </div>
  <script>
var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        randomColor = "#" + ("000000" + randomColor).slice(-6);
        document.bgColor = randomColor;
        document.getElementById("hexRandomColor").innerHTML = randomColor;
        </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML must be rendered first so the `<script>` should be at end tag `</body>`

```html
<body>


  <div class="container">
      <span id="hexRandomColor"></span>
  </div>
  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        randomColor = "#" + ("000000" + randomColor).slice(-6);
        document.bgColor = randomColor;
        document.getElementById("hexRandomColor").innerHTML = randomColor;
  </script>
</body>
```